# Podemos adicionar um novo bot no Chat?

Tags: novo-recurso, chat

Hoje o [@FranciscoMelicias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6291809/francisco-melicias) nos apresentou um bot utilizado no chat [iOSAndroidChaosOverFlow](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow). Esse bot funciona da seguinte forma:

Se você quer retornar uma busca no site, basta digitar **/search + termo** que ele faz uma busca no site e retorna uma postagem, por exemplo:

**/search android recyclerview** retorna
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse bot não se limita apenas ao site, pode buscar algo em fontes externas, como a wikipedia ou youtube, por exemplo. Para isso, basta digitar **/wiki + termo** ou **/youtube+ termo**, que teremos o resultado da imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Diante disso, eu tenho duas dúvidas, que são:

#### Esse bot seria útil para nós ou apenas "poluiria" o chat?

#### Sendo útil, existe a possibilidade de adicionar à [nossa sala do chat?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)

Comment: Só posso responder uma parte. Seria um pouco útil, não muito. Poluiria com os erros que o pessoal cometeria, e talvez com aquele negócio: "agora que tem, eu sou **obrigado** a usar o tempo todo". De qq forma, teria que experimentar.

Comment: @bigown Implementa e não avisa ninguém, ai so quem sabe usa :D

Comment: @bigown a ideia e fazer essa pergunta para os membros em primeiro lugar, coloquei a segunda pergunta apenas para ser mais fácil o diálogo com a equipe da SE. Bom, eu nao sei se seria bom ou ruim, como voce disse, apenas experimentando. Mas, eu achei a ideia interessante, por isso fiz o questionamento para ver a opiniao dos demais. Toda "ferramenta nova" esta sujeita a erros, no inicio. Vamos ver o que as pessoas acham. Agradeco pela sua opinião.  xD

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Se fosse tão simples. kkk

Comment: @Randrade sim, vale o experimento.

Comment: Eu acho meio complicada a idéia. Se fosse como IRC, que o bot pode responder em particular pra quem perguntou, ainda vai. Imagine se tiver 2 ou 3 conversas paralelas e em uma delas acontece de se fazer uma série de pesquisas até se achar o que está sendo procurado. Hoje o que acontece é que a gente troca de aba, pesquisa, e só cola de volta no chat depois de ter selecionado a informação, o ruído fica pra trás. O que é bem diferente do nosso "ruído intencional" de ficar descontraindo lá, pq uma pesquisa nem sempre vai devolver o resultado que a gente espera.

Comment: @Bacco Eu realmente não sei como funciona exatamente esse bot. Não sei como ele faz as pesquisas para retornar os resultados, mas no teste trouxe o conteúdo correto. Claro, isso iria sim aumentar o ruído do chat, mas não sei dizer o quanto, e nem se realmente seria usado. Mas a ideia do IRC eu achei interessante, não sei se tem como configurar isso. Caso tenha, seria um excelente recurso e que não afetaria o chat.